# Android - Camera app refuses to take pictures when provided directory

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I am developing my first android app and trying to create an intent to start the camera app, take a picture, and then come back to the application with the Uri of the picture.

When I use the following code, it works well but I can only take low-quality pictures.

```
    intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_TAKE_PICTURE);
```

When I try to define the file directory in order to save the picture in high quality however, the OK Button of the camera application just refuses to work and my picture is not saved... And I have absolutely no error message.
My guess is that the app just can't write on the directory I provide but I don't understand why and what I should do...

Here is the code :

```
    File file = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), 
            imageFileName);
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_TAKE_PICTURE);
```

And my permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem had two different sources: first the emulator seemed unable to access the external storage. I somehow fixed that by reducing the device's internal & external memory sizes.

The second problem came from my picture's name. Indeed, I used the following method to generate the name:

```
    String timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "picture_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
```

Which generated a name with ":" characters, making it impossible for the camera to create the file. I replaced it by the following:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");                    
    String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "picture_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
```

And now everything works fine ! :)

Comment: logcat is your friend.  Next time use logcat and I bet you'll find it much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
 intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

is wrong. intent to start camera should be like this

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
```

add this line and you are done.

make sure you have added these two lines in your manifest to use camera in your android application.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added those two but unfortunately it didn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

My approach is slightly different, but see if this piece of code helps. It functions just fine in my app.

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

File cameraFolder;

if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"your_folder_name");
else
    cameraFolder= StatusUpdate.this.getCacheDir();
if(!cameraFolder.exists())
    cameraFolder.mkdirs();

File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "your_folder_name/camera_snap.jpg");
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
Uri initialURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);

startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, reqcdCameraImage);
```

This will save an image with the name and extension: **camera_snap.jpg** in the specified folder and will also cast the same in an *Uri initialURI* for you to show it in an `ImageView` perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still have the same issue with your code... I'm starting to think that the problem comes from the emulator and that somehow the camera app is unable to write on the external storage...